# Columns Of The Diagonalization Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

After finding the eigenvectors, we can create a matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}\cdot A \cdot Q=D$ when $A$ is a matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

In which order should the columns of $Q$ be placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns of $Q$ are eigenvectors of $A$. They should be in the same order as the corresponding eigenvalues in $D$. That order itself doesn't matter; often we sort them, or just put them in the order that we found them.

Comment: That order itself doesn't matter even if we get different matrices?

Comment: @gbox If you reorder both the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors, you will always get the same matrix. The easiest way to see this is to note that if you reorder, the action on the eigenvector basis will be the same, then extend by linearity.